# Docker Error : An unexpected error occurred, Restart Docker Desktop

Tags: windows-11, docker, wsl2, docker-for-windows

I have installed Docker Desktop on Windows 11 using WSL 2 as the base.
It seems to be working fine internally.
However, every time I boot up or go to the settings screen,
I get the following error at the top of the UI: '**An unexpected error occurred. Restart Docker Desktop.**'
I have tried restarting, and I even disabled Hyper-V in case that was causing the issue.
Although it seems to be functioning without any problems, is it okay to continue using it like this?
Or is there a solution to fix it?

Comment: [Downgrade to Docker Desktop 4.19](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13518)

Comment: @Ramhound Then I guess I'll wait... Thank you!

Comment: Did downgrading to DD 4.19 solve your problem?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, Solved it! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although it seems to be functioning without any problems, is it okay to continue using it like this?
> Or is there a solution to fix it?

Based on the GitHub issue, Docker Desktop is failing to parse the version of WSL, it appears the reason for this is currently unknown. The suggested workaround is to downgrade to Docker Desktop 4.19.

Source: [An unexpected error occurred.Restart Docker Desktop #13518](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13518)